# Speed Up Website With High Resolution Images

Tags: images

i need help on how to speed up my Wordpress website with very high resolution images.
The thing is, i have W3 Total Cache installed, and i've enabled all cache options, also i have the images resized and reduced to about 130kilobyte each, maintaining the resolutions, but the site is still slow.
When i checked, the size of the webpage is 11.7MB, i've also used Wp Smush too,  but the website load time is still slow.
Please is there anything else i can do?
I really want the side to load fast.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just make the images smaller?

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. If i make it small, i'll loose the quality and clarity of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. i found a way to fix it. I created two sets of image, and placed them on different servers, CDN to be precise.
I had a small sized image, to display in the list of all product catalog, and i had a large image display, for the each product information.
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

your answer to your own question is a bit of a concern - why would your WP site not be automatically generating thumbnails for your product catalog? Your WP theme/plugins should be coded to automatically display the appropriate sized image relative for the different type of page display and also to what screen width (ie. device) it is being served on.

If your site is not doing this, then your site will not be served quickly and efficiently for all users, and your page speeds are going to suffer dramatically. And page load speed is a significant metric for Google.

As no URL was provided, it is not possible to be specific, but a webpage of 11.7Mb made up of 130k images is significantly large, and even with smaller sized images this is still going to be a large page. And if you are using a slider (which generally require most or all images to load prior to display) on certain pages, and additionally you aren't using lazy load on parts of your site where there are many images listed, then I'd be concerned with the load speed of your pages.

Additionally, apart from using a CDN/proxy for images and external scripts, you should be concerned with the *number* of scripts that are loading, whether they are optimised and minimised, and learn how to enqueue scripts to load in the footer of the page as all this will also have a big influence on your page display speed.

Comment: rule of thumb, if you feel that there is not enough information, comment don't answer.

Comment: wow... thanks for the markdown Mark... appreciate the positive support when trying to assist other people. I don't see where I've said I didn't have enough information to answer the question, (indeed, providing additional info), only that it was not possible to be specific.

Comment: "As no URL was provided, it is not possible to be specific," Answers should be specific as much as possible. Talking in generalities do not produce useful answers

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. As for Wordpress generating thumbs, i disabled this for the store page, i want to maintain the image in high resolution, which will eventually be large. Also, what you said about placing them in the footer is a good suggestion, which i overlooked, and also reducing the number of requests(scripts loading). I believe the speed will increase after i do all this.

Comment: Give it a rest, Mark... I did provide specific answers, just not in relation to the page @samsonade was referring to - this was pretty obvious "in context". Your overzealous moderation is just turning off people like me,  from using SE, who provide useful feedback and answers on a lot of different platforms. SE used to be a great place to hang out. rule of thumb... unless it's an error of glaring omission or commission, don't vote people down. We are not all perfect, and frankly with this sort of reception, have better things to do... and your repeated voting down is just pathetic...

Comment: no probs @samsonade happy to help, glad you got things sorted.